# Get Data with only of particular ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I am making a project by using rails API. Right now, I am getting all data of all IDs but I want to get the data of a particular ID. For that I have done:

Routes:

```
get 'all_club_post' => 'clubs#all_club_post'
```

Controller:

```
def all_club_post
active_posts = []
@posts = []
posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).pluck(:id)
@hide_posts = current_user.hide_posts.pluck(:post_id)
active_posts = posts - @hide_posts
active_posts.each do |post|
  @posts << Post.find(post)
  end
end
```

JBuilder:

```
json.posts{
json.array! @posts do |post|
    if post.club_id.present?
        json.id post.id
        json.counter_id post.id
        json.edit_id post.id
        json.user_id post.user_id
        json.club_id post.club_id
        json.post_text post.post_text
        json.created_at post.created_at.strftime('%d %b,%Y %H:%M')
        json.full_name post.user.full_name
        json.likes post.like_posts.count
        json.current_user_liked liked_post(post)

        json.like_posts{
          json.array! post.like_posts do |like_post|
            json.id like_post.id
            json.user_id like_post.user_id
            json.post_id like_post.post_id
            json.full_name like_post.user.full_name
          end
        }
    end
  end
}
```

Right now the result I am getting:

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 22,
        "counter_id": 22,
        "edit_id": 22,
        "user_id": 4,
        "club_id": 3,
        "post_text": "I work in jetsetgo",
        "created_at": "17 Mar,2018 09:06",
        "full_name": "Rahul Wadhwa",
        "likes": 0,
        "current_user_liked": false,
        "like_posts": []
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "counter_id": 21,
        "edit_id": 21,
        "user_id": 4,
        "club_id": 1,
        "post_text": "My Name is Amit.",
        "created_at": "17 Mar,2018 07:09",
        "full_name": "Rahul Wadhwa",
        "likes": 0,
        "current_user_liked": false,
        "like_posts": []
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "counter_id": 18,
        "edit_id": 18,
        "user_id": 2,
        "club_id": 1,
        "post_text": "HI",
        "created_at": "16 Mar,2018 13:18",
        "full_name": "Ravi Yadav",
        "likes": 0,
        "current_user_liked": false,
        "like_posts": []
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need data according to club Id. Like if I am in club_id: 3  'http://localhost:4200/club/3' that need the data of:

```
    {
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 22,
        "counter_id": 22,
        "edit_id": 22,
        "user_id": 4,
        "club_id": 3,
        "post_text": "I work in XYZ",
        "created_at": "17 Mar,2018 09:06",
        "full_name": "Rahul Wadhwa",
        "likes": 0,
        "current_user_liked": false,
        "like_posts": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the model itself has a method for this. Try

```
Post.find(params[:id])
```

That should do the trick. Try digging more [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this:

```
def all_club_post
  active_posts = []
  @posts = []
  posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).pluck(:id)
  @hide_posts = current_user.hide_posts.pluck(:post_id)
  active_posts = posts - @hide_posts
  active_posts.each do |post|
    @posts << Post.find(post)
  end
  ...
end
```

There are many things wrong with this including (and possibly worst of all) you are doing an N+1 query: You do a query to get `posts` and then you do N queries for `@posts << Post.find(post)`.

Rather, this could be something simple like:

```
def all_club_posts
  @posts = Post.where.not(id: current_user.hide_posts)
  ...
end
```